# Fatal exception "Method Illuminate\Validation\Rules\RequiredIf::__toString() must not throw an exception" when validating in laravel

Tags: laravel, validation

I am using Laravel. I would like to validate a complex request input but when I use the method `requiredIf` a fatal exception is launched and so I cannot read all the errors of the validator.
For example, if the input `$request->assistanceRequest['source']` doesn't exist, the validation doesn't work because the following exception is thrown:

```
Method Illuminate\Validation\Rules\RequiredIf::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught ErrorException: Undefined index: source
```

This is the code in the controller:

```
$rules = array( 
    'assistanceRequest.requestType' => 'required|exists:request_types,variable',
    'assistanceRequest.deliveryMode' => 'required|in:NORMAL,FAST',
    'assistanceRequest.creationDate' => ['required', 'regex:@^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]) (2[0-3]|1[0-9]|0[0-9]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-9]{2}$@'],
    'assistanceRequest.source' => 'required',
    'assistanceRequest.language' => ['required', 'regex:@^[A-Z]{2}$@'], 
    'assistanceRequest.country' => ['required', 'regex:@^[A-Z]{2}$@'], 
    'customer.customerId' => 'required|integer',
    'customer.login' => 'required',
    'customer.companyName' => 'required',
    'customer.phoneNumber' => 'required',
    'customer.email' => ['required', 'regex:&^\S+@\S+\.\S+$&'], 
    'vehicle.plateNumber' => 'required', 
    'vehicle.Country' => ['required', 'regex:@^[A-Z]{2}$@'], 
    'vehicle.frenchRegistration' => '',
    'vehicle.vin' => 'required|min:17|max:17',
    'vehicle.variationId' => 'required|integer|max:9999999',
    'vehicle.makeLabel' => 'required',
    'vehicle.modelLabel' => 'required',
    'vehicle.variationLabel' => 'required',
    'vehicle.bodyLabel' => Rule::requiredIf(function () use ($request) {
        return $request->assistanceRequest['source'] == "ATD"; //example problem
    }),
    'vehicle.releaseDate' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d', 
    'vehicle.specificitiesOptions' => '',
    'vehicle.mileage' => Rule::requiredIf(function () use ($request) {
        return $request->assistanceRequest['requestType'] !== "SERVICE_PLAN"; 
    }),
    'vehicle.distanceUnit' => Rule::requiredIf(function () use ($request) {
        return $request->assistanceRequest['requestType'] !== "SERVICE_PLAN"; 
    }),
    'requestInformations.category' => Rule::requiredIf(function () use ($request) {
        return ($request->assistanceRequest['requestType'] == "TECHNICAL_DATA" or $request->assistanceRequest['requestType'] == "REPAIR_METHOD" or $request->assistanceRequest['requestType'] == "WIRE_DIAGRAM") and $request->assistanceRequest['source'] == 'ATD'; //chiedere e modificare 5
    }),
    'requestInformations.subCategory' => Rule::requiredIf(function () use ($request) {
        return ($request->assistanceRequest['requestType'] == "TECHNICAL_DATA" or $request->assistanceRequest['requestType'] == "REPAIR_METHOD" or $request->assistanceRequest['requestType'] == "WIRE_DIAGRAM") and $request->assistanceRequest['source'] == 'ATD'; //chiedere e modificare 5
    }),
    'requestInformations.informationCode' => Rule::requiredIf(function () use ($request) {
        return ($request->assistanceRequest['requestType'] == "TECHNICAL_DATA" or $request->assistanceRequest['requestType'] == "REPAIR_METHOD" or $request->assistanceRequest['requestType'] == "WIRE_DIAGRAM") and $request->assistanceRequest['source'] == 'ATD'; //chiedere e modificare 5
    }),
    'requestInformations.dataLabel' => Rule::requiredIf(function () use ($request) {
        return ($request->assistanceRequest['requestType'] == "TECHNICAL_DATA" or $request->assistanceRequest['requestType'] == "REPAIR_METHOD" or $request->assistanceRequest['requestType'] == "WIRE_DIAGRAM") and $request->assistanceRequest['source'] == 'ATD'; //chiedere e modificare 5
    }),
    'requestInformations.cuCode' => Rule::requiredIf(function () use ($request) {
        return ($request->assistanceRequest['requestType'] == "TECHNICAL_DATA" or $request->assistanceRequest['requestType'] == "REPAIR_METHOD" or $request->assistanceRequest['requestType'] == "WIRE_DIAGRAM") and $request->assistanceRequest['source'] == 'ATD'; //chiedere e modificare 5
    }),
    'requestInformations.text' => 'required',
    'requestInformations.errorCodes' => Rule::requiredIf(function () use ($request) {
        return $request->assistanceRequest['requestType'] == "BREAKDOWN" or $request->assistanceRequest['requestType'] == "ERROR_CODE";
    }),
    'requestInformations.troubles' => Rule::requiredIf(function () use ($request) {
        return $request->assistanceRequest['requestType'] == "BREAKDOWN" or $request->assistanceRequest['requestType'] == "ERROR_CODE";
    }),
    'requestInformations.controls' => Rule::requiredIf(function () use ($request) {
        return $request->assistanceRequest['requestType'] == "BREAKDOWN" or $request->assistanceRequest['requestType'] == "ERROR_CODE";
    }),
); 

$validator = Validator::make( $request->all(), $rules);
```

Can help? Is it an easy way to solve that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your  `Rule::requiredIf(function (){})` rules you have used `$request->assistanceRequest['source']` variable and error shows that `source` key not exists in `$request->assistanceRequest` array.

Solution 1: use `??` operator:

```
...
    'vehicle.bodyLabel' => Rule::requiredIf(function () use ($request) {
        return $request->assistanceRequest['source'] ?? null == "ATD"; //example problem
    }),
...
```

Solution 2: use `isset()` function:

```
...
    'vehicle.bodyLabel' => Rule::requiredIf(function () use ($request) {
        if(!isset($request->assistanceRequest['source'])) return false;
        return $request->assistanceRequest['source'] ?? null == "ATD"; //example problem
    }),
...
```

Solution 3: use `request()` helper:

```
...
    'vehicle.bodyLabel' => Rule::requiredIf(function () use ($request) {
        return request('assistanceRequest.source', null) == "ATD"; //example problem
    }),
...
```

> Note that you have used it in multiple validation rules and you have to change all of them